# How to test angular-timer with gulp-cdnizer test option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-timer, gulp-cdnizer

I have the following gulp code for [gulp-cdnizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cdnizer). I would like to ensure that [angular-timer](https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) is working by specifying a [`test` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cdnizer#optionsfilestest) as I did for angular in the example below.

How can I specify the `test` option for angular-timer?

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(source + '*.html')
        .pipe(gulpcdnizer({
            bowerComponents: './dev/components',
            defaultCDNBase: "//my.cdn.host/base",
            allowRev: true,
            allowMin: true,
            files: [

                /* angular */
                {
                    file: '**/angular/*.js',
                    package: 'angular',
                    test: 'window.angular',
                    cdn: 'cdnjs:angular.js:${ filenameMin }'
                },
                {
                    file: '**/angular-timer/dist/*.js',
                    package: 'angular-timer',
                    cdn: 'cdnjs:angular-timer:${ filenameMin }'
                }

            ]
        })) // replace local dependencies with cdn equivalents
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest)); // copy html to dest directory
});
```